# Definition of a group written in formal logic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic

Is the formal logic in these axioms correct?

A group is a nonempty set $G$ with a binary operation $*$ that satisfies the following axioms:

- $(a * b) \in G \; \forall \;a,b \in G$
- $a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c \; \forall \; a,b,c \in G$
- $\exists \; e \in G : a * e = e * a = a \; \forall \; a \in G$
- $\forall \; a \in G \; \exists \; a^{-1} \in G: a * a^{-1} = a^{-1} * a = e$

In particular, in the last two axioms notice the difference of where the "for all" is placed.
The third axiom is meant to state that there exists an $e$ in $G$ that is a identity for all $a$ in $G$ under $*$.
While the last axiom is meant to state that for every $a$ in $G$ there exists an inverse $a^{-1}$ in $G$ under $*$.

Comment: correct it is....

Comment: If you are concerned about the formal logic I think you should be very careful with the placement of quantifiers.  I would recommend rewriting the third statement as$$\exists \; e \in G : \; \forall \; a \in G : a * e = e * a = a$$and similarly for the first two.

Comment: The axioms as given are not sentences of first-order predicate calculus. In particular, the placement of the universal quantifiers is not right.  There is also nothing connecting the $e$ of the fourth axiom with the $e$ of the fifth. As a very informal description, it is sort of OK. From the formal point of view, quite far from right.

Comment: Total pedantry would identify the operation as an "infix binary operation" since that is how you have used it.  Most people aren't total pedants, so this is excessive.

Comment: To address André Nicolas's objection about $e$, you could state that a group is a tuple $(G,*,e,{}^{-1})$ comprising a nonempty set, an infix binary operation, a distinguished element of $G$, and a unary postfix operation, together satisfying the following axioms...

Comment: One can avoid the constant symbol by combining the last two sentences suitably into a single sentence. And a single binary function symbol is enough, if that's what we want. A more serious issue for formalization is the $\in$ symbol. In first-order group theory, one would omit all the $\in G$ stuff.

Comment: By definition, a binary operation on a set $S$ is a function $S \times S \to S$, so the first axiom is unnecessary.

Comment: You either need to fully parenthesize things or switch to Polish notation or reverse Polish notation.  All axioms have to follow the formation rules.  Even if we did that though, we couldn't tell if you had correct axioms until we knew which formation rules you had at work.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't see why we couldn't rewrite the formation rules to allow for quantifiers to succeed (instead of preceding) a formula.  It wouldn't result in any consistency or any ambiguity so far as I can tell (unlike how if we rewrote the formation rules to say that "a $\land$ b" is a formula).  Of course though we'll have to rewrite the formation rules *first*.

Comment: Certainly. I was thinking OP's question as analogous to asking whether a particular paragraph is written in grammatical English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see [List of first-order theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories) under the heading : **Groups**.

In addition, you can check the details in every mathematical logic textbook, like Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001), page 93.

*Note*

As you can see, there are different possibilities; what make the (little) differences are the symbols used as "basic".

In order to be "formal", you have to specify a *language* : an alphabet and the syntactical rules for building expressions (see comments above).