# Doubt regarding the identical nature of groups that are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have been told that $2$ isomorphic groups are necessarily identical from the standpoint of group theory, but I can't digest the fact, let a group $(G, *)$ be isomorphic to $(H, \#)$ by a certain map $\psi$, how can these two groups be identical if $*$ and $\#$ are two different operations?

Comment: Isomorphic groups are **not** identical **but** every true group-theoretical statement about one has a corresponding true group-theoretical statement about the other. If every English word had a corresponding exact equivalent French word, and vice versa, then the two languages would be isomorphic but they still wouldn't be identical. Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128344/confusion-regarding-the-identity-or-non-identity-of-two-groups

Comment: Take for example the cyclic groups, first written additively, and then written multiplicatively. They look totally different first, but are obviously isomorphic. Take an example, say $C_3=\{e,a,a^2\}$ and $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. The more examples you do the better.

Comment: I think the best way to understand the difference between representation of a group, abstraction of a group and how isomorphism between group representations relate to group abstraction is described very well here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH0oCDa74tE . Dont need to watch it all, but first 10 minute deal quite well with this topic

Comment: @TStancek Yes, but be careful. Instead of watching videos, reading answers here one has to do examples *yourself*. One cannot learn to play piano only from watching videos. The same is true for math.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I agree, but the request is not to solve a problem, but to get an insight.  And one does always cling to use the analogies and abstractions that worked for him. Even most professors and teachers do this. But if someone creates content focused on giving insight to a broad spectrum of people, and judging by the success of the channel does it well, he will have much better grasp on what analogies and visualisations have the best chance to succeed.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers! It really helped me to gain an insight to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not *identical*, only isomorphic. Consider $D_3\cong S_3$.

One case in which they *are* identical is when $H\le G$, $G$ is finite, and $H\cong G$.

This doesn't work if $G$ is infinite. Consider $k\Bbb Z=\{ka\mid a\in\Bbb Z\}$ for $k\notin\{0,\pm 1\}$, which is clearly a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ where $k\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z$, but $k\Bbb Z\neq\Bbb Z$. We need them not to be identical in order to define the group $\Bbb Z/k\Bbb Z$ of order $|k|$.